# How to keep HTML element shaking/moving after I've added a class

Tags: javascript, html, css, typescript, css-animations

I'm working on small angular application, and on some point I need to select some of my rows that will be deleted, so I decided to put class on them when they are selected and I did it this way:

1.) HTML

```
<div id={{product.id}} *ngFor="let product of products; let i = index;" class="panel panel-default index-panel">
    <div class="order-checkbox">
                <div class="checkbox">
                  <label style="font-size: 2em">
                    <input type="checkbox" value="" (change)="toggleMerge($event, product.id)" [(ngModel)]="product.isOrderChecked">
                    <span class="cr"><i class="cr-icon fa fa-check"></i></span>
                  </label>
                </div>
              </div>
</div>
```

As you can see when checkbox is checked I will call a me thod `toggleMerge($event)` :

2.) .ts file

```
toggleMerge(event, id) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      $("#" + id).addClass('animated shake');
    }
    else {
      $("#" + id).removeClass('animated shake');
    }
  }
```

And this works, but how can I keep it shaking while it's selected?

Thanks guys
Cheers

Comment: it would be useful if we'd have your css code as well. The problem is probably there. Most likely not setting the animation to repeat indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS, add this:

```
.animated.shake {
    animation: [animation name](shake?) [animation duration](1s?) /*IMPORTANT PART:*/ infinite;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your animation to infinite iteration by adding:

```
.animated.shaking  
{ 
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
```

also, using classlist add() and remove() doesn't support white-spaces so may change you script to:

```
toggleMerge(event, id) {
  if (event.target.checked) {
     $("#" + id).add('animated');
     $("#" + id).add('shake');
  }
  else {
     $("#" + id).remove('animated');
     $("#" + id).remove('shake');
  }
}
```